# Is there a screenshot > Report embed method for TestNG which is available for Cucumber?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, testng

Is there a screenshot embed method for TestNG which is available for Cucumber?

I have the following Cucumber method up and running, but is there a similar method for JUnit or TestNG which will append images to created reports (XML reports)

```
public void close_browser_window(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question has 2 paths.
One is actually taking the screenshot and the other one is attaching it to an XML report.

So, in TestNG in order to take a screenshot you can override the OnTestFailure method like so:

```
public class onFailure extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {

    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE)); 
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Screenshots\\Regression\\"+nameVar+"_"+envVar+".png")); 
    }

}
```

Then without too much hassle you can use Extent Reports which can attach the screenshot to your report, check out the community edition [here](http://extentreports.com/community/)! 
*Update after OP's comment:*

[image]

Comment: thanks allot for the reply, I understand Extent generates HTML reports do you know whether also generates an XML report?

Comment: sorry Gbru, my bad, actually TestNG after each test run automatically creates xml reports, I'll attach an image

Comment: thanks appreciate it does this append to the image to the report with the above image?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the 'above' image but yes when a test fails you will be able to see a screenshot appended in the exact step which failed. Maybe this could be of some help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSjwgjVl4P4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: thanks again, is this also able to generate XML reports? much like cucumber

Comment: I don't think so but for sure you can use Cucumber together with TestNG (which generates XML reports automatically). Then ExtentReports will pick it up from there, not sure if this exactly what you are after though  :)

Comment: A pleasure if I was of some help m8, TestNG is actually a much better choice vs Junit (from the point of view that JUnit has stopped evolving a while ago), best of luck Gbru!

Comment: yea i agree, just Cucumber is more suited with JUnit from what i have heard :[

Comment: You will notice that JUnit and TestNG are very very similar. They even have the same annotations! There is also plenty of info on the Internet, I'm sure you will be fine